# Where to find database tables in Google cloud platform?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have created a spring boot application that inserts some data in GCP MySQL database.When I'm trying to get data from getAll(),it is showing all data in my table but in GCP Mysql,I can't see any table.
Image attached.[image]

Comment: Do you expect to see in a UI the table contents? If so I want to clarify that you won't find any table content displayed in the console. To see your data you will need to connect into your Cloud SQL instance via `gcloud sql connect` and fetch you data with `select * from table`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Chris32 also pointed out, the Google Cloud Web console will not provide you any information about the tables or, in general, the contents of a schema that a Cloud SQL instance database contains.

In your screenshot, Cloud SQL is only showing you the different databases associated with the Cloud SQL instance.

If you want to see the tables associated with a certain schema defined in those databases, first, you need to whitelist the IP from which you will access the database.

Once you have performed this step, you can connect to the database with an appropriate client for the database product: I recommend [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) for example in your case.

As @guillaumeblaquiere indicated in his answer, please, be aware that opening the database to the internet, even only from your ip address, is always a potential security risk.

To mitigate that risk, if you want to benefit from the rich UI approach offered by tools like the above mentioned MySQL Workbench, you can, for example, only whitelist your IP when necessary, and remove this ability when you do not need to connect to the database from this tool.

Or, following a similar approach, you can create a [bastion host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host). Basically, you can provision a GCE machine that will only be powered up when necessary. You can then install the tool in the machine and connect to it when you need to (it is more straightforward in the case of a Windows machine probably), although typically you will configure a SSH tunnel from your machine to the Cloud SQL instance through that machine instead.

Answer (score 5):

IMO, the right answer is a mix of comment of @Chris32 and the answer of @Jccampanero.

Personally, I don't recommend to allow list your IP. It's not secure. You can access to the database following 2 ways

1. Use [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) to open a tunnel to Cloud SQL database. Then, use your database explorer (MySQL workbench as suggested by jccampanero, it's free. I prefer datagrip personally). You can access the Cloud SQL database through the tunnel, usually (if you follow the documentation and the port 3306 isn't used on your computer): `localhost:3306`
2. Use a bash terminal, on Cloud Shell or on your computer, with mysql client already installed. then run the command `gcloud sql connect` to connect the database; the mysql client is automatically run by this command. After logged in into the database, you can perform a `use <database>;` and a `show tables;` to explore it.

*Note, in both cases you need a public IP. If not, you can have a look to [the article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-sql-with-private-ip-only-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-de4ac23ce98a) that I have written*

Comment: I totally agree with you @guillaumeblaquiere +1. In any case, please, see my updated answer, I tried to clarify the suggested approach.